# Samsung Keyboard language switch + Accessibility service

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, languages, accessibility

I've faced an issue that Samsung Keyboard disables functionality of language switching using space bar... after upgrade to 4.4.2 KitKat. That was messed on a forums a little bit and everybody agreed that Accessibility services should be disabled to enable this functionality...

But I have 7 services and DO want to use at least 4 of them... e.g. one of them forward notifications to my Sony SmartWatch... It become pretty useless without this service...

I really like Samsung Keyboard and want to use it... (I do use continuous input switching to voice input some times... and really love space bar switching of language)

How can I enable both language switching and Accessibility services?

GT-I9505

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/105277/18093) explains why it's not possible to change the keyboard layout when an accessibility service is on.

I faced the problem on my Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3 (I9300XXUGOE1), installed [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), and use it instead of the default Samsung keyboard.