# suddenly can't change language in keyboard

Tags: keyboard, languages

I used to use 3 languages in my keyboard English Chinese and Filipino, using it by just sliding the spacebar; however recently this feature disappeared. I can't change language anymore even tho 3 languages in settings. please help

Comment: What device, Android version, and keyboards are you using?

Comment: thank you Andrew T. Samsung keyboard android version 4.4.2

Answer (score 4):

Try disable all accessibility services. It may be a security measure to prevent malicious apps from changing keyboard without user interaction, since an accessibility services can automate the process without the user knowing.

Comment: actually accessibility features  are off .

Comment: I can confirm this works in Android 4.4.4.  Note you must disable the services, not individual accessibility features.  http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/how-use-androids-accessibility-service-3341094/ shows the basic idea, but the appearance will vary.  Just look for the Accessibility section of settings, then Services within that.

Comment: @ballzak, do you have any proof that there is such a security feature?

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev Only circumstantial. I''l update my answer.

Comment: Thats the answer, worked for me